# AdSense responsive code, different data-ad-format for small/large screens

Tags: responsive, adsense

In my bootstrap grid I have included a Google AdSense responsive ad unit on far right side bar column. This far right column shows below the content on small screens.

Having data-ad-format="auto" unfortunately shows a rectangle ad unit on all screens. What I'm trying to get is a vertical ad unit for larger screens and a rectangle ad unit for smaller screens.

Is it possible to have data-ad-format default to vertical on large screens and auto on small screens?

Of course the server side PHP don't know what screen I'm serving my responsive website to.

Comment: My best shot is playing around with CSS's max/min-width/height on the surrounding div.

Comment: in this page https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124?hl=en Google also recommended to do this by CSS.